# C++11 code with thread giving error with clang version 3.5 on rpi3 but same works on my ubuntu linux machine

Tags: c++11, raspberry-pi, pthreads, clang, raspberry-pi3

I am having a very small script as below :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::thread th([]() {
        std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    });

    th.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling it as below :

```
clang++ -o demo demo.cpp -lpthread -std=c++11
```

When i execute my binary after successful compilation, it gives below output : 
on ubuntu linux machine  :

```
Hello, World!
```

on my rpi3 :

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
```

my clang version on both are :

on rpi3 :

```
Raspbian clang version 3.5.0-10+rpi1 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)
Target: arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
```

on linux :

```
clang version 3.8.1-24+rpi1 (tags/RELEASE_381/final)
Target: armv6--linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

How to make this work ?

Comment: Just speculating here, but there is a very large gap in version numbers between the two compilers. Could be a bug in the (old) RPi compiler or the standard library?

Comment: Yes, i thought so, but i found this thread facing similar issue where clang and std::thread don't go along. [link] https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=131856

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Clang. See [bug report **23165**](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23165). This appears even in clang 3.7 with `-std=c++11`.

As per the last comment on the bug report it seems to have been fixed in an update.

> Verified fixed, with an update I just received via the llvm-toolchain-utopic channel to the clang-3.7 package. (package version: 1:3.7~svn234704-1~exp1)

Comment: Yeah i saw this too. In one of my pi3 i have clang v3.8 where this issue is solved. But i don't know how to update my clang version from 3.5 to 3.8

Comment: If you face issues with updation, you can uninstall existing version and install new version

Comment: Given that clang 3.5 was released more than four years ago (Sep 2014), you probably ought to figure out how to update it.   See http://releases.llvm.org for a list of the 21 releases that post-date 3.5